# Database on own webserver

Tags: mysql, database, webserver

I want to install a database, preferably [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/), on my domain ([Strato](http://www.strato-hosting.co.uk/)) to make my database accessible remotely.
Is it possible?
Has somebody tutorials on it?
I'm absolutelly inexperienced in this area. The only webserver I have ever set up was Apache (XAMPP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strato is a hosting provider. If you have the basic service, you can't install or use MySQL databases.

For other levels of service, see [their FAQ](http://www.strato-faq.co.uk/746).

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's apt-get install mysql or zypper install mysql. It depends what Linux it's installed. Most likely you can also build from the sources. Then you need gcc and all tools. Apt-get install gcc or zypper install gcc. When you can disclose a bit more information maybe we can help?